Upload multiple files as IEnumerable<IFormFile> and send additional information about the files in JSON within an HTTP POST request
I am aware of single file upload and binding with an API request model, but I am failing to achieve multi-file upload with their additional information in JSON.
Here are my models:
OilTankImageDTO.cs:
public class OilTankImageDTO
{
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    public string ImageCode { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AltText { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

TankPhotoTool2Response.cs:
public class TankPhotoTool2Response
{
    public IEnumerable<OilTankImageDTO> Images { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    public string AuthoId { get; set; }
    public string TownHash { get; set; }
}

I am trying to bind this request model with a POST action. So far, I have researched available responses on Stack Overflow, but I do not see those answers working.

What have you tried? What you found works, even though it doesn't look like what you expected. IFormFile is only on the server to represent files uploaded through an input type='file' element in a form. A form can have multiple fields and all of them (including the files) are uploaded using a multipart/form-data request. That means you need to POST a MultipartFormDataContent with the file and data you want. You can't use IFormFile in a request model

I made a small working sample you could reference:
    public class OilTankImageDTO
    {
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

    }

    public class TankPhotoTool2Response
    {
        public IEnumerable<OilTankImageDTO> Images { get; set; }
        public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    }

Controller
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("test")]
        public void test(TankPhotoTool2Response model)
        {
            var result = model;
        }
    }


